# how to cumulatively number zero entries in matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix Composed of zero and one entries as follows

```
1 0 0 1
1 0 0 1
0 0 0 0
```

And i need to replace the entries with Numbers as follows

First zero should be 1, second should Be 2...nth zero to be n

Then the first one should Be n+1, second one should Be n+2...i'th one to Be n+i

Resulting in The Following matrix

```
9  2  5  11
10 3  6  12
1  4  7  8
```

This should work for any 3xn matrix with zero and one entries anywhere.

Thanks

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use logical indexing:

```
idx = ~A(:); %// Indices of zeros
A(idx) = 1:nnz(idx);
A(~idx) = nnz(idx) + 1:numel(A);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps you need to take, to get the 0 part done.  Rinse and repeat to get other numbers.  The 0's in "result" are the locations that need to get updated.

```
>> a
a =
     1     0     0     1
     1     0     0     1
     0     0     0     0
>> ix = find(a==0);
>> result = zeros(size(a));
>> result(ix) = 1 : numel(ix)
result =
     0     2     5     0
     0     3     6     0
     1     4     7     8
```